# Creating a 1200x600 mm tile texture layout from multiple textures

Tags: texturing

I have 5 tree textures measuring 1200 by 600 millimeters, which I need to randomly decompose on a tile texture, where the tree tiles have an offset of 33%.

Before that, I collected such textures manually, but now there is a large batch of tile types and I would like to automate this process. An example of such a texture: [image]